# Find the probability using Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Approximate the probability that $100$ elements, each of which works for time $T_{i}$, will provide $100$ hours of work in total. It is known that $E[T_{i}]=1$ and $D^2[T_{i}]=1$.

I have introduced a new variable
$$Z=\sum_{i=1}^{100}T_i$$
so that
$$E[Z]=E[nT_i]=n$$
$$D^2[Z]=D^2[nT_i]=n^2D^2[T_i]=n^2$$
where $n=100$.

I'm not sure about the following steps:
$$Pr(\frac{nT_i-n\cdot n}{n \sqrt{n}}\geqslant\frac{100-n\cdot n}{n\sqrt{n}})=1-Pr(\frac{nT_i-n\cdot n}{n\sqrt{n}}<\frac{100-n\cdot n}{n\sqrt{n}})=1-\Phi(\frac{100-n\cdot n}{n\sqrt{n}})$$

Is my solution correct? I'm really not sure about this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is no question in your exercise.
- I do not know what do you mean with $D^2$. If that is the variance, usually indicated with $V(X)$ or $\sigma^2_{X}$,

and assuming that the question is to calculate the probability $\mathbb{P}[\sum_i X_i>100]$ you can apply the CLT that states:

$$\frac{\sum_i X_i-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$$

Your probability is

$$\mathbb{P}[Z>\frac{100-100\cdot 1}{1\cdot \sqrt{100}}]=1-\Phi(0)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Note:

As per the fact that $\mathbb{E}[\sum_i X_i]=n\mu$ the result is $\frac{1}{2}$ without applying the CLT

Comment: The question was to approximate the probability that the elements will provide 100 hours of work. I made the same assumption as you, because calculating Pr(Z=100) wouldn't use CLT (at least I think so). I do see my error now, thank you!